# Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::My()

Tags: php

I am getting this error when I call for the function My() for the second time. The first time (when I'm calling for the user_id) everything seems to be fine.. Stripped down code:

```
class User {
    function My($field) {
        global $user;
        global $db;
        global $sessions;

        if ($sessions == 2) {
            $user = $db->Row("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'"); 
            return $user->$field;
        }
    }
}

$user = new User;

class Index {
    function Startup() {
        global $user;

        $user_id = $user->My("user_id");
        $name = $user->My("firstname")." ".$user->My("surname");
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please stop. Do not continue writing like this. I am sorry to say, but this is not how you're supposed to work with classes in PHP (or in fact any OO language). Please edit your question to tell us, what is that you want to achieve, and I am sure we can find a better solution for you.

Comment: Thanks Mchl, I realise I am not following the regular OOP way, and I am currently reading an article to use the better alternatives to globals, but I don't get why its so bad what I am doing.

Comment: You just had your first experience. Because `$user` is a global object, you can't use it as a `$user` in your code. Similar with `$db` and `$sessions`. If instead you passed these variables as arguments to constructor and stored them as instance variables of `User` class, you would avoid this risk. That's just one thing. Please lookup topics such as `encapsulation` `separation of concerns` `polymorphism`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry my first answer was incorrect!

Because you define $user global in both My() and Startup() you are reffering to the same data in both contexts.

The frist time everything is fine because $user has been initialized to a user object somewhere in your code. But the $db->Row() method inside your My() function changes the global $user to an stdClass which has no My() opreation.

Solution: remove the word global before $user in My()

Comment: Tim, thanks. I solved it by doing:
$user_id = User::My("user_id");
$name = User::My("firstname")." ".User::My("surname");

Answer (score 0):

You have to initalize the variable first like

```
$user = new User();
$user->my();
```

Also please never use global unless you know what you are doing.